# Output shape error in custom layer of Keras/TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, keras-layer

I wrote my own Keras/Tensorflow layer. Passing images into it works fine, but using it in combination with other layers gives the underlying error. Somehow the output shape of my custom layer should be wrong, or some kind of `"Nonetype"`.

In short, the custom layer transforms the image from colorspace A to B, then makes a histogram out of some channels. It's a preprocessing layer for the discriminator of a `GAN`, and therefore has to be a part of the generator backpropagation model.

```
from keras import backend as K
from keras.layers import Layer

class Identity_Loss(Layer):

def __init__(self, output_dim, **kwargs):
    self.output_dim = output_dim
    super(Identity_Loss, self).__init__(**kwargs)

def build(self, input_shape):
    super(Identity_Loss, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this at the end

def call(self, x):

    assert isinstance(x, list)
    input_1,input_2=x

    # Transform BGR to RGB and than to HSV
    channels = tf.unstack (input_1, axis=-1)
    RGB    = tf.stack   ([channels[2], channels[1], channels[0]], axis=-1)
    RGB=tf.cast(tf.multiply(tf.truediv(tf.add(RGB,1.0),2.0),255.0),dtype=tf.int32)
    RGB=tf.cast(RGB,dtype=tf.float32)
    HSV=tf.image.rgb_to_hsv(RGB,name=None)

###########################################################
     SV=HSV[:,:,:,1:]
############################################################

 #make mask binary and multiply with image
        y=tf.math.greater(input_2, 0)
        y=tf.cast(y, tf.float32, name=None)
        HSV_mask = tf.math.multiply(HSV, y)
 #Count color occurences ###########################
        shape=tf.shape(HSV_mask)
        length=shape[1]*shape[2]

 #transform
        Hue=HSV_mask[:,:,:,:1]
        Hue=tf.cast(tf.multiply(Hue,255.0),dtype=tf.int32)
        Hue2 = tf.reshape(Hue, [length])

 #prevent that the shape changes
        filler=tf.range(0,length, 1,dtype=tf.int32) 
        filler = tf.reshape(filler, [length])
        Hue3 = tf.stack([Hue2,filler],axis=-1)
        Hue3 = tf.reshape(Hue3, [2*length])

 #Count Hue       
        y1, idx1, count1 = tf.unique_with_counts(Hue3)

        maximum=tf.cast(tf.math.reduce_max(count1[1:257]),dtype=tf.int32)
        diff=tf.reshape(count1[1:257],(16,16))
        diff=tf.expand_dims(diff, axis=-1)
        diff=tf.expand_dims(diff, axis=0)
        diff=tf.truediv(diff,maximum)
        diff=tf.cast(diff,dtype=tf.float32)

    return [SV,HSV_mask,diff]

def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
    assert isinstance(input_shape, list)
    return [[None,None,2],[None,None,3],[None,None,1]]
```

This is corresponding error message when passing the custom layer output into another CNN layer for example:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-89-3caaa8c77e0c> in <module>()
      5 c,d,e=mod([d,input_B])
      6 
----> 7 dd=model(d)
      8 
      9 bb = Model([input_A,input_B],[c,d,dd])

3 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, **kwargs)
    487             # Actually call the layer,
    488             # collecting output(s), mask(s), and shape(s).
--> 489             output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
    490             output_mask = self.compute_mask(inputs, previous_mask)
    491 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py in call(self, inputs, mask)
    581             return self._output_tensor_cache[cache_key]
    582         else:
--> 583             output_tensors, _, _ = self.run_internal_graph(inputs, masks)
    584             return output_tensors
    585 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py in run_internal_graph(self, inputs, masks)
    796                         input_shapes = unpack_singleton(
    797                             [x._keras_shape for x in computed_tensors])
--> 798                         shapes = to_list(layer.compute_output_shape(input_shapes))
    799                         uses_learning_phase = any(
    800                             [x._uses_learning_phase for x in computed_tensors])

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/layers/convolutional.py in compute_output_shape(self, input_shape)
    191     def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
    192         if self.data_format == 'channels_last':
--> 193             space = input_shape[1:-1]
    194         elif self.data_format == 'channels_first':
    195             space = input_shape[2:]

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: I think `input_shape[0]` (i.e. batch dimension) should be added to all the elements of the list returned by `compute_output_shape`.

Comment: I really thank you, struggled there so much. Man thats really a dumb failure. Thanks a lot <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** add batch dimension to output shape of layer returned by `compute_output_shape` method.

**Long answer:** Keras models always work on a batch of input samples and therefore all the input shape and output shape values in a Keras layer contain the batch dimension. Therefore, you need to consider that as well when computing the output shape of the layer:

```
def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
    return [
        [input_shape[0], None, None, 2],
        [input_shape[0], None, None, 3],
        [input_shape[0], None, None, 1]
    ]
```

Since batch size does not change from layer to layer, therefore you just need to add `input_shape[0]` to the returned shapes as above.

Comment: hey you helped me last time a lot, i have another problem, can you may help me? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61259623/keras-error-an-operation-has-none-for-gradient

Comment: IS this still true? I've tried to implement this function in my custom layer, but I still get the same incorrect shape `(4, None, 128)` printed in the summary and tensorflow complains it's the wrong shape. I also had an error in that function for a few runs and it was never picked up. It doesn't seem like it's even being called...